# How I can determine if the page is checkout/cart?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, onepage-checkout, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have something but this checks if in the cart are products:

```
  public function customerLogin(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
   {    
           if (Mage::helper('customerredirect')->isEnabled() && !Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->getRedirectregister()){    
               $lasturl = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getLastUrl();
             if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer(), 'checkout/cart') === false){
                 if (! preg_match("#customer/account/create#", $lasturl) && Mage::helper('customerredirect')->isoptionEnabled('login_customerredirect')) {
                          if($this->_CustomerGroup()) {
                           $_session = $this->_getSession();
                           $_session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customerredirect')->setRedirectOnLogin());
                         }
                }
            }
         }
        Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->setRedirectregister(false);
   }
```

and I add this in the /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/link.phtml

```
<?php if ($this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout() && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()):?>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Proceed to Checkout')) ?>" class="button btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout<?php if ($this->isDisabled()):?> no-checkout<?php endif; ?>"<?php if ($this->isDisabled()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif; ?> onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>';"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Proceed to Checkout') ?></span></span></button>
<?php else: ?>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Proceed to Checkout')) ?>" class="button btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout<?php if ($this->isDisabled()):?> no-checkout<?php endif; ?>"<?php if ($this->isDisabled()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif; ?> onclick="window.location='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'); ?>';"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Proceed to Checkout') ?></span></span></button>
<?php endif?>
```

All I want to do is when I press on the Proceed to Checkout if the user is not login to be redirected to login and the autoredirect to checkout onepage.

After more searches i found something that need to be put in the onepage checkout:

```
      if (!$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) {
             header("Location: /customer/account/login/");
             exit();
      }
```

but this is generally how I can implement this for my needs?

Edit: Maybe this can be a solution?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/64085/22840
Thank you

Comment: For me, this does not make sense. Let's assume that the user(logged in user) has just arrived on checkout cart. In this moment, you want to automatically redirect him to checkout onepage, withought letting him to see the cart ?

Comment: Hi Alex, I edit my post now, please take a look again

Comment: So i need something like this, to make some checks if the user is not in the shopping cart page, then when he is login the redirect will be to My Account, if is in the shopping cart and login then must be redirected to onepage checkout

Comment: is ok? now make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add below code of file 
app\design\frontend\Your-Theme\Your-Package\template\persistent\customer\form\login.phtml

```
<?php if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer(), 'checkout/cart') !== false) {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setIsFromCheckout('1');
      }
?>
```

Then you need to override function _loginPostRedirect of  Mage_Customer_AccountController class

```
protected function _loginPostRedirect()
    {
        $session = $this->_getSession();

        if (!$session->getBeforeAuthUrl() || $session->getBeforeAuthUrl() == Mage::getBaseUrl()) {
            // Set default URL to redirect customer to
            $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($this->_getHelper('customer')->getAccountUrl());
            // Redirect customer to the last page visited after logging in
            if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
                if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(
                    Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::XML_PATH_CUSTOMER_STARTUP_REDIRECT_TO_DASHBOARD
                )) {
                    $referer = $this->getRequest()->getParam(Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::REFERER_QUERY_PARAM_NAME);
                    if ($referer) {
                        // Rebuild referer URL to handle the case when SID was changed
                        $referer = $this->_getModel('core/url')
                            ->getRebuiltUrl( $this->_getHelper('core')->urlDecode($referer));
                        if ($this->_isUrlInternal($referer)) {
                            $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($referer);
                        }
                    }
                } else if ($session->getAfterAuthUrl()) {
                    $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($session->getAfterAuthUrl(true));
                }
            } else {
                $session->setBeforeAuthUrl( $this->_getHelper('customer')->getLoginUrl());
            }
        } else if ($session->getBeforeAuthUrl() ==  $this->_getHelper('customer')->getLogoutUrl()) {
            $session->setBeforeAuthUrl( $this->_getHelper('customer')->getDashboardUrl());
        } else {
            if (!$session->getAfterAuthUrl()) {
                $session->setAfterAuthUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl());
            }
            if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
                $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($session->getAfterAuthUrl(true));
            }
        }
        //add condition to check is from checkout page
        if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getIsFromCheckout()){
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsIsFromCheckout();
                $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage');
            }else{          
                $this->_redirectUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true));
            }
    }
```

Comment: I use a custom extension for checkout I have Magestore OneStepCheckout, so is not work, this extension have own login popup, so i need to pass that login

Comment: link.phtml code is not working for you?Whats problem you are facing?

Comment: the link is work, when the customers are not login, the button go in the login form, my problem is after they add username and password and press login, instead checkout they are redirected to my account

Comment: I have edited my answer please check and let me know if any

Comment: hi but i don't use the default checkout

Comment: No need to worry about that just simple change $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage'); of function as per your checkout url

Comment: i add the code unfortunately i don't know why, but even I am in the shopping cart page, when i press Proceed to Cart button, is going me to login, add credentials and is redirect me on the My account

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35977/discussion-between-prashant-valanda-and-robertd).

Answer (score 7):

That is how you can check for the cart page

```
// Check for cart page
if (Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_cart_index') {
    // The current page is the cart
} else ... whatever you want to do then
```

To check if the cart is empty or not use

```
$isEmpty = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCount() > 0
```

Comment: hi thank you but is not work on my code

Comment: You can use this in your function and then it depends on what you want to do

Comment: I write there exactly how I want to be, can you made this for me please?

Comment: in fact the idea is like this, i need to check if the user is login and is in the checkout/cart, if it yes then redirect to checkout/onepage, if not the redirect to my account.

Comment: something like this? if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer(), 'checkout/cart') === false){

Answer (score 2):

Working like a charm !

Add this to your `/customer/form/login.phtml`

```
<?php if (strpos(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getLastUrl(), 'checkout/cart') !== false) {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setIsFromCart('1');

      }
      else{
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setIsFromCart('0');
      }
    ?>
```

then the observer:

```
public function customerLogin($observer)
     {
         if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getIsFromCart() == 1){
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage'));
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
         }

         else{ 
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('cust‌​omer/account'));
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
         Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setIsFromCart('0');

     }
```

Thats all... good luck

Comment: Hi Alex i do this logic before, but my client won't this. he want when the customers is on the shopping cart, when they press Procced to Cart button to go on login and then to Checkout page directly page, otherwise if they are in other pages after login must go in My account

Comment: ok..i will try to implement it

Comment: thank you so much, for redirect the url's after login I use this extension Magehit_CustomLoginRedirect-0.0.1 and the checkout extension is  Magestore OneStepCheckout

Comment: Please see my edited answer :)