# Check if currenty page is checkout cart

Tags: cart, page

How can I check if the current page is the checkout cart page?

I tried this, but that does not work. Then it is displayed on all pages.

```
<?php if(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')): ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this :

```
$handle = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles();
if(in_array('checkout_cart_index',$handle)){
    // cart page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$requestUrl = Mage::app()->getModuleName() . DS . Mage::app()->getControllerName();
if($requestUrl == 'checkout/cart'){
   //cart page action logic...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but that does not seem to work.

Comment: I have updated code please check.

Comment: Rakesh,please the answer at  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102564/how-i-can-determine-if-the-page-is-checkout-cart

Comment: @AmitBera, I have close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
 $module = $request->getModuleName();
 $controller = $request->getControllerName();
 $action = $request->getActionName();
 if($module == 'checkout' && $controller == 'cart' && $action == 'index')
 {
   //Cart Page
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but that code is still displaying on other pages as well, for example the homepage.

Comment: updated answer check it